# Remove old remote branches from Git

Tags: git

When I use bash autocompletion in Git, it keeps showing me branches of old remotes that I don't have anymore. When I do a `git branch -la` it shows those old remotes and branches while a `git branch -l` won't. A `ls .git/refs/remotes/` also shows them. However, they are not present in my *.git/config* and neither are they shown when I run `git remote show`.

So how do I get rid of them because my autocomplete list is too long right now.

I have already tried:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
rm .git/refs/remotes/theoldremote
git remote prune theoldremote
```

I'm also aware of the fact that I can just re-clone the repo but that's just cheating ;-)

Comment: Note: a `git remote rm` now (git 2.0.1, June 2014) delete first the remote tracking branches. That should help in avoiding cleaning up old branches. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24984473/6309)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766525/git-branch-av-showing-remote-branch-that-no-longer-exists

Comment: Here is my another answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44129766/3835843

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Git does not delete the (local) remote-tracking branches automatically if the branch was deleted in the remote repository. Additionally, before V2.0.1 remote-tracking branches were in some cases not deleted when you removed the remote from your git config (see VonC's answer).

To delete stale remote-tracking branches (branches that were deleted in the remote repository) for one of your remote repositories, run

```
git remote prune <remote>
```

To cite the man page or `git remote`:

> prune
>
> Deletes all stale tracking branches under <name>. These stale branches have 
>   already been removed from the remote repository referenced by <name>, 
>   but are still locally available in "remotes/<name>".
>
> With --dry-run option, report what branches will be pruned, but do 
>   not actually prune them.

However, from your question it seems you manually removed `.git/refs/remotes/theoldremote`, so Git no longer knows about the remote repository that the remote-tracking branches belonged to. That's not how you're supposed to do it.

The normal way to remove a remote repository is to run

```
git remote rm <remote>
```

This will remove the remote from your `.git/config`, and will delete the remote-tracking branches.

If you just delete the directory under `.git/refs/remotes/`, the branches will remain behind. Then you will need to remove them manually:

```
git branch -rd <remote>/<branchname>
```

You need option `-r` to delete a remote branch.

Comment: Nope, that's not it. It says `fatal: 'kolichikov' does not appear to be a git repository`.

Comment: For automatic pruning of remote branches on fetch/pull, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18718936/968201

Comment: If you find this slow, upgrade to the newer Git (2.0.1+ IIRC) where this is fixed (over 100x faster).

Comment: Note to prune users : [Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-prune) says "_In most cases, users should run `git gc`, which calls git prune._". However note that `git gc` is not compatible with `--dry-run`.

Comment: `git branch -rd <remote>/<branchname>` was what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

I use

```
git push origin :remote_branch
```

to remove a branch from server.

```
git remote prune origin
```

to remove remote references which do not exist on server anymore

Comment: Nope, that's not it. It says `fatal: 'kolichikov' does not appear to be a git repository`

Comment: Alex, you have to run the command inside the repository folder not in your home folder...

Comment: Worked very well for me; what remained were stale branches I subsequently cleaned up too :-)

Answer (score 6):

Note: while git remote prune is the answer, know that, starting with git 2.0.1 (June 25th, 2014), a `git remote rm` **starts by removing the remote tracking branches**.
So hopefully, one shouldn't have to cleanup old branches after a `git remote rm`.

See [commit b07bdd3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b07bdd3472886cbdd412ee3e7489273522c43133) by [Jens Lindström (`jensl`)](https://github.com/jensl)

#### `remote rm`: delete remote configuration as the last

> When removing a remote, delete the remote-tracking branches before deleting the remote configuration.
>   **This way, if the operation fails or is aborted while deleting the remote-tracking branches, the command can be rerun to complete the operation**.

---

But if you have to, a simple `git fetch` can be enough, provided you have set first:

```
git config --global fetch.prune true
cd /path/to/repo
git config remote.origin.prune true
```

Comment: See also https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9e768bb77762765f739fffb5c09d0888f3de20e

Answer (score 5):

Push *nothing* to a branch to delete it:

`git push remote :remote_branch`

It's somewhere in the docs but it isn't really obvious.

Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: "It's somewhere in the docs but it isn't really obvious." such is `git`

Comment: By "remote" i meant your remote repository name. Such as "origin" or whatever. But I'm starting to think that you meant something else than simply deleting the remote branch.

Comment: Something else such as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072171/how-do-you-remove-an-invalid-remote-branch-reference-from-git

Answer (score 4):

Ok I've got it. The problem was that the remotes don't exist anymore, but they do somewhere in the git database. I re-added the remotes, then did

```
git remote prune theremote
git remote rm theremote
git gc --prune=now
```

After that they disappear from the list. Somehow I didn't remove them correctly before I guess.

Comment: I tried everything from a bunch of sources, and the only thing that worked was to re-add the problem remote and then remove it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting confused when remote branches that had been deleted on the server side were still appearing when I ran:

```
$ git branch --all
```

The following command fixed this for me (on git version 2.25.0):

```
$ git remote update --prune
```