# Intellij delete multiple local branches

Tags: intellij-idea

Using Intellij IDE (I have version 2017.3.5) is there a way to delete multiple local git branches at once

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can delete multiple branches in IntelliJ IDEA directly.

Go to tab Git / Log (bottom of IDE) *(or via IDE top menu Git / Show Git Log)*.
Here open the Tree View on the left side and right mouse click.
Check this picture:

[image]

Note: You will not see this menu item on current branch so select another or multiple of them.

Source: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-131571

Comment: This should be the accepted answer nowadays. IntelliJ clearly supports deleting multiple branches at once, even across multiple git roots.

Comment: Agreed, added an update to mine to refer to this one. Great job @mojmir.novak

Comment: Whew, thank you. Previously, i was using other software to do that. Now i can rest in peace. Haha.

Answer (score 26):

**// Update Feb 2021:**

As mojmir.novak pointed out here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65954247/1546042 you can do this now in IntelliJ. To remove only merged branches, see answer below:

**// Older update:**

To clean-up (old) feature branches that have been merged to master you can use the terminal to clean it up.

> To delete all local branches that are already merged into the currently checked out branch:
>
> ```
> git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|master|dev)" | xargs git branch -d
> ```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6127884/1546042 for more details.

**Cleaning up using run config"**

In order to clean up multiple branches at once, using intelliJ. You need to install the Bash Support plugin and use it to create a run config that executes a script with the above command.

1. Install [BashSupport plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4230-bashsupport)
2. Create script with the command. (e.g. `~/scripts/clean-branches.sh`)
3. Create a new `Bash` run config.
4. Link to the script created in step #2.
5. Provide working directory of the repo you want to clean.
6. Run it to clean the branches.

Comment: I create a branch for each change i make; after time this quickly piles up. Intellij provides a way to delete individual local (and remote) branches. so i was curious if there was a way to do select multiple and delete

Comment: I suspected as such, as I've found myself in the same position :-) See updated answer.

Comment: @MarquisBlount see new update, I've found a way to "automate" it with IntelliJ using the BashSupport plugin.

Comment: @MarquisBlount did you file a feature request? Might be helpful to add the URL here so people can vote on it. I want this too!

Comment: @jon_wu sorry, no I never got around to it

Answer (score 17):

There is a Plugin available for this:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10059-git-branch-cleaner/

To use it once it's installed, in the main menu go to:

VCS > Git > Delete Old Branches

Comment: I always used to do this too, but in my current version, this no longer seems to be available

Answer (score 2):

Have been through the pain of cleaning up the unused branches, and found this plugin.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10059-git-branch-cleaner/

But I was not able to see the `VCS > Git` menu on my Mac - IntelliJ
[image: VCS > Git - not found]

But was successful in finding a similar option under `git > context-menu - Delete old branches...`

[image: Git - Context menu - delete old branches]

I am not sure if there is a default option or this is because of the above-mentioned plugin.

Sharing to help others who don't have VCS > Git menu like in my case

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to delete multiple branch on Git Extensions.
http://gitextensions.github.io/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).