# GitHub flow when deleting remote branches

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a fork from an upstream repo. Locally I'm on branch `foo`. I pushed `foo` up to my repo on GitHub and opened a PR into `upstream/master` and had it merged.

After merging I deleted the the `foo` branch on GitHub and also locally:

```
git branch -d foo
```

But if I view my log with:

```
git log --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --decorate --all
```

Then I still see `origin/foo`.

I read in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17471123/2909897) to use:

```
git remote prune origin
```

Which successfully removed the `origin/foo`.

- Is this the correct GitHub workflow when deleting a feature branch?

process:

```
delete branch on GitHub -> delete branch locally -> prune the origin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is one possible workflow, and you can set (since Git 1.8.5):

```
git config remote.origin.prune true
```

That way, a simple `git fetch` is enough.

[Another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003515/6309) is to delete locally, then push that deletion:

```
$ git push origin --delete <branch_name>
$ git branch -d <branch_name>
```