# 'git branch -a' shows upstream repository that no longer exists

Tags: git

`git branch -a` shows

```
master
remotes/origin/master
remotes/upstream/bugfix/corrupted-deb
... (many more remotes/upstream branches)
```

The repository `upstream` no longer exists. How to delete the zombie branches `remotes/upstream/bugfix/corrupted-deb` etc for good?

File `.git/config` contains no more than

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@<myurl>
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Any intentional reference to `upstream` is gone since long.

The command `git remote prune origin` [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766525] doesn't affect `upstream`. The obvious variant `git remote prune upstream` results in `fatal: 'upstream' does not appear to be a git repository ...`

Comment: Does `git remote -v` show `upstream`?

Comment: No, it only shows two lines (fetch/pull) refering to `origin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
git update-ref -d refs/remotes/upstream/bugfix/corrupted-deb
```

Sometimes you may have a symbolic ref like:

```
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
```

To remove `remotes/origin/HEAD`, run:

```
git symbolic-ref -d refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
```

To remove all `remotes/upstream`, try:

```
git for-each-ref refs/remotes/upstream --format="%(refname)" | while read ref;do
    git update-ref -d ${ref}
done
```

Comment: Yes, `git update-ref -d refs/remotes/....` works. In reality, though, I have tons of dead upstream branches (I edited my question to say that). Any way to delete them all at once?

Answer (score 1):

`git branches -a` is just telling you that you have a file locally in your `.git` folder (created through `git fetch`, at some point). Just remove it:

```
.git/refs/remotes/upstream/bugfix/corrupted-deb
```

To exemplify i created a small test project and created, manually, a file `.git/refs/remotes/test/feature/mybranch` pointing to the sha of a single commit i made.

Running `git branch -a` now yields:

```
/c/dev/remotetest (master)
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/test/feature/mybranch
```

After removing the file `.git/refs/remotes/test/feature/mybranch` running `git branch -a` now yields:

```
/c/dev/remotetest (master)
$ git branch -a
* master
```

/Martin